# Auditing SQL Server data changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm looking at changing our Auditing process for our SQL Server 2005 databases and I came across Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2008.

This looks like a good idea, and I'm tempted to try it, but before I do has anyone used it in a commercial environment and what are your thoughts?

I noticed when I was reading about CDC in the MS help, it said that audit data would usually be kept for a couple of days. That's not possible here, I'd like to keep the data indefinitely, does anyone know of problems with this approach?

If this isn't a good solution for reasons I'm unaware of, have you any other solutions for  auditing of data changes. I'm keen to use a system that can be implemented across the board on any tables I desire.

I'm after the basic: "Before, After, Who By, When" information for any changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CDC should is just a means to an end in my opinion. I have implemented audit trail solutions in the past and they have involved the use of Triggers. This got to be very messy and performance intensive for highly transactional databases.

What the CDC gives you is the ability to log the audit data without the use of triggers, but you still need a means to take that data into a permanent table. This can be done with a mirror table for each table to be audited or a single table that tracks all the changes to all the tables (I have done the latter).

**Here are some links with additional information on how it was done using triggers:**
[SQL Audit Trail](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/)
[sql-server-history-table-populate-through-sp-or-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349524/sql-server-history-table-populate-through-sp-or-trigger)

Here's an open source audit tracking solution that uses LINQ: [DoddleAudit](http://www.codeplex.com/DoddleAudit)

Comment: I see, I've just read some more on CDC and understand what you're saying. It seems CDC benifits from being asynchronous. I quite like your idea of the single table to track all changes, however it seems to me that with "highly transactional databases" this table could get very big, very quickly.

Comment: Hey, I've finally got round to having a look at what you were saying. I was wondering how do you keep track of who made the changes in your system? In principle CDC seems to be fairly easy to set-up and provides some nice functionality.

Comment: In my setup, each table has 4 additional columns: CreatedDate,CreatedBy,UpdatedDate,UpdatedBy. I fill the last 2 columns with the username/date in my sql update statements. I use that determine who changed what.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've ended up using triggers for now. Anything I've read for CDC has said it could be used for Auditing, although that's not necessarily what it is designed for. I was worried about using something it was indented for. In the end I've implemented a system that creates Audit data similar to CDC albeit by using Triggers. I've followed a similar system of 4 types of operation and it seems to be OK.

Comment: Would you please approve my answer?

Comment: Be very wary of  using CDC out of the box, it expires the data in just a few days which is not acceptable for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 7):

*Quite late but hopefully it will be useful for other readers…*

Below are several different techniques for auditing with its pros and cons. There is no “right” solution that would fit all. It depends on the requirements and the system being audited.

**Triggers**

- **Advantages**: relatively easy to implement, a lot of flexibility on what is audited and how is audit data stored because you have full control
- **Disadvantages**: It gets messy when you have a lot of tables and even more triggers. Maintenance can get heavy unless there is some third party tool to help. Also, depending on the database it can cause a performance impact.

**CDC**

- **Advantages**: Very easy to implement, natively supported
- **Disadvantages**: Only available in enterprise edition, not very robust – if you change the schema your data will be lost. I wouldn’t recommend this for keeping a long term audit trail

**Traces**

- **Advantages**: a lot of flexibility on what is being audited. Even select statements can be audited.
- **Disadvantages**: You would need to create a separate application in order to parse trace files and gather useful information from these.

**Reading transaction log**

- **Advantages**: all you need to do is to put the database in full recovery mode and all info will be stored in transaction log
- **Disadvantages**: You need a third party log reader in order to read this effectively

I’ve worked with several auditing tools from [ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com/) but there are also good tools from [Idera](http://www.idera.com/) (compliance manager) and [Krell](http://krell-software.com/) software (omni audit)

[ApexSQL Audit](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_audit.aspx) – Trigger based auditing tool. Generated and manages auditing triggers

[ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) – Allows auditing by reading transaction log

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use the "Audit" feature and stock data on a file, app log or system log. Find more infos at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Sql Server job which removes the captured changes after two days. You can also extend this clean up time as per your convenience, or make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/) scripts, you could define what are the table(s) you want to have the audit or all the table define on your database. Plus, tvf for single record viewing of history. Check the link, for details.