# asp.net dynamic data web site : passing default value while inserting/updating records

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am working in ASP.NET Dynamic Data web application and have an issue of passing default value while inserting/updating records. In my application all table has following common column:

- CreatedBy (Default Value : Logged in user)
- CreatedDate  (Default Value : DateTime.Now)
- modifiedBy  (Default Value : Logged in user)
- ModifiedDate (Default Value : DateTime.Now)

I want to keep these column hide in `Insert` and `Edit` page and want that default value will be inserted automatically in the respective column.

Please suggest me.

Thanks
paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution i have implemented finally:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
   {
      e.Values.Add("CreatedBy", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
      e.Values.Add("CreatedDate", DateTime.Now);
    }

 protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
      e.OldValues.Add("ModifiedBy", null);
      e.OldValues.Add("ModifiedDate", null);
      e.NewValues.Add("ModifiedBy", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
      e.NewValues.Add("ModifiedDate", DateTime.Now);
   }
```

Comment: A more thorough explanation of what you're doing: [Updating Values Before Insert on ASP.NET Dynamic Data Website Using Entity Framework](http://batesits.com/tag/dynamic-data/)

Answer (score 2):

I see you are doing simple Auditing have a look at my blog post here [Basic Auditing for Dynamic Data with Entity Framework 4.x](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2012/02/basic-auditing-for-dynamic-data-with.html) hope that helps.

It's never good to do this sort of thing in the page, it's always best to do it in your data model/layer. You can use my [A New Way To Do Column Generation in Dynamic Data ...](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2010/02/new-way-to-do-column-generation-in.html) to hide the columns in all pages.

Comment: For auditing we have used sqlserver 2008 auditing. I just wanted to hide these field from UI. As createdby/CreatedDate is mandatory field in DB using scaffolding=false was not possible. Finally i resolved it by adding these field/value in FormView1_ItemInserting event. Anyway thanks for the information. I have read numbers of article written by you on DD and got lots of help. Thanks a lot>>

Answer (score 0):

**Ref:**
[Maintaining a Log of Database Changes - Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml)

> In order to maintain a history of changes to the database's data we
>   need to record every insert, update, and delete to some sort of
>   "history" table. In addition to capturing the data that was inserted,
>   updated, or deleted, we also need to note what user made the
>   modification, as well as the date and time it was made.

More Reference:

[Best design for a changelog / auditing database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201527/best-design-for-a-changelog-auditing-database-table)
[Log changes to database table with trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899825/log-changes-to-database-table-with-trigger)

**To customize ORM Entity Framework check following links:**

[How to use Default column value from DataBase in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584556/how-to-use-default-column-value-from-database-in-entity-framework)
[How to: Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. For history we have separate transaction table. what i need is suppose i do not want to display a column in insert/edit dynamic data page even that column is NOT NULL in DB level. Now while inserting/updating record of that entity i want to pass some default value in insert/update query.

Comment: Okk..when you are creating tables then specify default value for columns or use stored procedure specifying default values....

Comment: it is not possible to specify default value in table as createdby/modified is variable(loggedin user). I am using dynamicdata with EF and DD automatically do insert/updated job so no scope of writing SP. Is there any workaround in DD???

Comment: check the added links for entity framework for reference on this topic

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit different from Paul's requirements.

In the file *DynamicData\PageTemplates\Insert.aspx.cs* I made edits to show my defaults for new records in any table having the shared fields. The user can still put in something else on insert.

```
public partial class Insert : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected MetaTable table;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table = DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestMetaTable(Context);
        var values = table.GetColumnValuesFromRoute(Context);

        // set default values for meta data of new records across all tables
        // unknown values will be skipped
        values.Add("creationDate", DateTime.Now);
        values.Add("modificationDate", DateTime.Now);
        values.Add("modificationUser", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(
            HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1));

        FormView1.SetMetaTable(table, values);
        DetailsDataSource.EntityTypeFilter = table.EntityType.Name;
    }
    [...]
}
```

For editing records with existing values, I made changes to some *DynamicData\FieldTemplates* files.

```
public partial class Text_EditField : System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...

        // show current user as value for the modification user upon editing records
        if (Column.Name == "modificationUser")
        {
            FieldValue = Page.User.Identity.Name.Substring(Page.User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

It will show the updated value on the page for editing, but after updating the changes won't persist! An additional change to the Edit page template is required:

```
    protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // make sure a meta data update is always triggered by setting a different old value
        // required for the edit components
        if (e.OldValues.Contains("modificationUser"))
        {
            e.OldValues["modificationUser"] = string.Empty;
            e.OldValues["modificationDate"] = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
```