# Is there a way to know where a record came from

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to know where an inserted row in a table came from? For example knowing if someone inserted it through back-end or some stored procedure created it or even when it was created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log record changes in SQL server in an audit table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737723/log-record-changes-in-sql-server-in-an-audit-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you add some sort of audit trail to your records, like a CreatedByID or a SourceSystemID or something like that. Same goes for when it was added (need a CreatedOn datetime column that is reliably filled in).