# Create checksum for fields of a record

Tags: vb.net, checksum

I have a database with several fields of various types (basically String, Integer and Decimal). I'd like to create a control field to store something like a checksum in order to detect simple value changes from any among those fields.

I first thought of collecting `.GetHashCode` from each field value just before calling *INSERT INTO* against the database, and performing some arithmetical operation complex enough to be difficult form someone to manually replicate, and putting this result as value for the control field:

```
Function ControlFieldValue(ParamArray values() As IEnumerable(Of Object)) As Long
    Dim retval As Long
    For Each v In values
        If retval = 0 Then
            retval = v.GetHashCode
        Else
            retval = retval Mod v.GetHashCode
        End If
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
```

But I don't know how effective this would be. Is there some simple implementation  in VB.NET for such purpose? Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't persist the result of `GetHashCode`. Microsoft does not guarantee it to be stable across versions nor across platforms.  Differences in both areas have occurred in the past: the calculated hash has been different on different platforms (x32 vs x64), and the calculated hash has changed between versions of the .NET framework.

Comment: Depending on your backing DB, you may be able to log changes.  See [Log record changes in SQL server in an audit table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737723/log-record-changes-in-sql-server-in-an-audit-table) for one possible solution.

Comment: @Craig, thanks, I'll discard that approach.

Comment: @TnTinMn, no, it's Access in some cases, SQLite in others.