# How to compare each column and display the difference alone

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

Please explain the best way to compare two rows and display the fields along with the change value.

Example

| ID | EmployeeID | EmployeeName | Address1 | Address2 | Salary | UpdatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 501 | Johnson | 2nd Ave | 108 | 850 | 04/04/2020 |
| 2 | 501 | Johnson | 2nd Ave | 109 | 900 | 04/05/2020 |
| 3 | 501 | Johnson | 3rd Ave | 109 | 950 | 04/06/2020 |

Each row is an new version of the previous row.
Based on the input value, the previous row need to be compared and difference should be highlighted.

Example:
Input: 3

| Column | NewValue | OldValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Address1 | 3rd Ave | 2nd Ave |
| Salary | 950 | 900 |

Input: 2

| Column | NewValue | OldValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Address2 | 109 | 108 |
| Salary | 900 | 850 |

The fields names should dynamically picked while comparing and should ignore the primary key and updateddate fields alone.

Thanks

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Please show the code you currently have so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Could you create a trigger on that table and log the changes in a separate table like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737723/log-record-changes-in-sql-server-in-an-audit-table)?

Comment: what you have tried so far in this context ?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. How do plan to handle different data types, e.g. `NewValue` and `OldValue` might be `money` or `nvarchar(max)`? Is `ID` guaranteed to be unique and dense, i.e. start at `1` and count _nicely_? What is The Answer for input `1`?

Comment: @WAMLeslie We did not want to log in a table and preferred to compute the difference only when required. Thanks a lot for providing reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that will dynamically unpivot your data via a bit a JSON.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efb8477d081adfd4e1629169d1df70aa)**

```
;with cte as ( 
Select * 
      ,OldValue = lag(Value,1) over (partition by EmployeeID,[Key] order by UpdatedDate)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]
                      ,Value
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  ) ) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('ID','UpdatedDate')
             ) B
)
Select [EmployeeID]
      ,[Column]=[Key]
      ,[NewValue] = [Value]
      ,[OldValue]
 From  cte
 Where [Value]<>[OldValue]
 Order By UpdatedDate desc
```

**Returns**

```
EmployeeID  Column      NewValue    OldValue
501         Address1    3rd Ave     2nd Ave
501         Salary      950         900
501         Address2    109         108
501         Salary      900         850
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was trying to implement.

Comment: @JackA If you found this helpful, feel free to ACCEPT the answer.